# Background UIImage becomes a Zombie delegate

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-management, uinavigationcontroller, uicolor

One of the screens in my application has a high resolution background that can take just a tad too long to to load on an older device.

My solution is to preload in the image in the delegate and then reuse it.

Thus, I have a property in my delegate:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong, retain) UIColor *fabricColor;
```

and I load the image in didFinishLaunching:

```
fabricColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
```

However, when I try referencing the delegate.fabricColor in my navigation controller, it is a zombie:

```
AppDelegate *dg = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate]; 
self.view.backgroundColor = dg.fabricColor; //Doesn't work
```

**How do I prevent this from happening, so that I can use the fabricColor?**

A few notes:

- I am **not** using ARC.
- The first line in my delegate's dealloc is "[fabricColor release]"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use property when setting value to your ivar to retain:

```
self.fabricColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bg.png"]];
```

In your code you simply assign autoreleased value to your instance variable without retaining it - so it gets deallocated some time later before you try to use it

Comment: Thank you Vladimir! That solved the whole problem. Can you again elaborate why self.propertyName is needed? (i.e. what the difference is between using self and not using it?)

Comment: @eitan27, +colorWithPatternImage method returns autoreleased object so you need to retain it to retain it (otherwise it will get deallocated as in your case) - you can do that by using retaining property (so actually automatically synthesized setFabricColor: method will be called where old ivar value will be released and new one will be retained). With properties you get a lot of memory-management functionality out of the box so I use them whenever possible